# How to check md5sum between two directories?

Tags: linux, diff, hashsum

I have two directories. I want to check whether all files in one directory are same as that of other directory or not by using `md5sum`. If the `md5sum` results in a difference, I want to apply `diff`.

So how to check `md5sum` and find out whether MD5 values are same or not?

Answer (score 4):

first get `md5sum` of directory1 all files and write to a file.

```
find dir1 -type f -exec md5sum '{}' + >dir1_checksum.txt
```

Then find all directory2 files checksum and output those checksums didn't match using `grep -vf filename`.

```
find dir2 -type f -exec md5sum '{}' + | grep -vf dir1_checksum.txt
```